# how to compare two data frames in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I have two exactly same dataframes for comparison test

```
     df1
     ------------------------------------------
     year | state | count2 | count3 | count4|
     2014 | NJ    | 12332  | 54322  | 53422 |
     2014 | NJ    | 12332  | 53255  | 55324 |
     2015 | CO    | 12332  | 53255  | 55324 |
     2015 | MD    | 14463  | 76543  | 66433 |
     2016 | CT    | 14463  | 76543  | 66433 |
     2016 | CT    | 55325  | 76543  | 66433 |
     ------------------------------------------
     df2
     ------------------------------------------
     year | state | count2 | count3 | count4|
     2014 | NJ    | 12332  | 54322  | 53422 |
     2014 | NJ    | 65333  | 65555  | 125   |
     2015 | CO    | 12332  | 53255  | 55324 |
     2015 | MD    | 533    | 75     | 64524 |
     2016 | CT    | 14463  | 76543  | 66433 |
     2016 | CT    | 55325  | 76543  | 66433 |
     ------------------------------------------
```

I want to compare with these two dfs on count2 to count4, if the counts doesn't match then print out some message saying it is mismatching.
here is my try

```
     val cols = df1.columns.filter(_ != "year").toList
     def mapDiffs(name: String) = when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", null).otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name")).as(name)
     val result = df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), "year").select($"year" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)
```

it then compares with the same state with the same number, it didn't do what I wanted to do

```
     ------------------------------------------
     year | state | count2 | count3 | count4|
     2014 | NJ    | 12332  | 54322  | 53422 |
     2014 | NJ    | no     | no     | no    |
     2015 | CO    | 12332  | 53255  | 55324 |
     2015 | MD    | no     | no     | 64524 |
     2016 | CT    | 14463  | 76543  | 66433 |
     2016 | CT    | 55325  | 76543  | 66433 |
     ------------------------------------------
```

I want the result to come out as above, how do I achieve that?

edits, also in a different scenario if I want to compare only in one df, col to cols how do I do that?
like

```
 ------------------------------------------
 year | state | count2 | count3 | count4|
 2014 | NJ    | 12332  | 54322  | 53422 |
```

I want to compare count3 and count 4 cols to count2, obviously count3 and count 4 do not match count 2, so I want the result to be

```
-----------------------------------------------
 year | state | count2 | count3    | count4   |
 2014 | NJ    | 12332  | mismatch  | mismatch |
```

Thank you!

Comment: Good catch!! I missed those

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, I have updated the question and added a new scenario..

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: all I am asking is how do you join the first row of df1 with first row of df2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataframe `join` on `year` won't work for your `mapDiffs` method.  You need a row-identifying column in df1 and df2 for the `join`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("2014", "NJ", "12332", "54322", "53422"),
  ("2014", "NJ", "12332", "53255", "55324"),
  ("2015", "CO", "12332", "53255", "55324"),
  ("2015", "MD", "14463", "76543", "64524"),
  ("2016", "CT", "14463", "76543", "66433"),
  ("2016", "CT", "55325", "76543", "66433")
).toDF("year", "state", "count2", "count3", "count4")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("2014", "NJ", "12332", "54322", "53422"),
  ("2014", "NJ", "12332", "53255", "125"),
  ("2015", "CO", "12332", "53255", "55324"),
  ("2015", "MD", "533",   "75",    "64524"),
  ("2016", "CT", "14463", "76543", "66433"),
  ("2016", "CT", "55325", "76543", "66433")
).toDF("year", "state", "count2", "count3", "count4")
```

Skip this if you already have a row-identifying column (say, `rowId`) in the dataframes for the`join`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val rdd1 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex.map{
  case (row: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id)
}
val df1i = spark.createDataFrame( rdd1,
  StructType(df1.schema.fields :+ StructField("rowId", LongType, false))
)

val rdd2 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex.map{
  case (row: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id)
}
val df2i = spark.createDataFrame( rdd2,
  StructType(df2.schema.fields :+ StructField("rowId", LongType, false))
)
```

Now, define `mapDiffs` and apply it to the selected columns after joining the dataframes by `rowId`:

```
def mapDiffs(name: String) =
  when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name", $"l.$name").otherwise("no").as(name)

val cols = df1i.columns.filter(_.startsWith("count")).toList

val result = df1i.as("l").join(df2i.as("r"), "rowId").
  select($"l.rowId" :: $"l.year" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

// +-----+----+------+------+------+
// |rowId|year|count2|count3|count4|
// +-----+----+------+------+------+
// |    0|2014| 12332| 54322| 53422|
// |    5|2016| 55325| 76543| 66433|
// |    1|2014| 12332| 53255|    no|
// |    3|2015|    no|    no| 64524|
// |    2|2015| 12332| 53255| 55324|
// |    4|2016| 14463| 76543| 66433|
// +-----+----+------+------+------+
```

Note that there appears to be more discrepancies between df1 and df2 than just the 3 `no`-spots in your sample result.  I've modified the sample data to make those 3 spots the only difference.

Comment: Thank you @Leo C I missed those mismatch numbers! They are supposed to be “no” on all of those which doesn’t match. I will try your method in a bit. Thank you

Comment: Hello, I've the same problem. I tried this solution but running into compiler error. can someone help me on this? here is the code snippit, 
val cols = sourceDF.schema.fields.map(_.name)
val result = sourceDF.as("l").join(targetDF.as("r"), s"${srcParirions}_Val").select(s"l.${srcParirions}_Val" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

def mapDiffs(name: String) =
      when(s"l.${name}" === s"r.${}name}", s"l.${name}").otherwise("no").as(name)

Comment: @Ponns, rather than describing your problem in a comment, I would suggest that you describe it along with formatted code/sample data in a separate question.