# In Spark scala, how to check between adjacent rows in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I check for the dates from the adjacent rows (preceding and next) in a `Dataframe`. This should happen at a key level

I have following data after sorting on key, dates

```
source_Df.show()
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| key | code   | begin_dt   | end_dt     |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| 10  |  ABC   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-08 |
| 10  |  BAC   | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-15 |
| 10  |  CAS   | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-21 |
| 20  |  AAA   | 2017-11-12 | 2018-01-03 |
| 20  |  DAS   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-12 |
| 20  |  EDS   | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-16 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

When the dates are in a range from these rows (i.e. the current row `begin_dt` falls in between begin and end dates of the previous row), I need to have the lowest begin date on all such rows and the highest end date.
Here is the output I need..

```
final_Df.show()
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| key | code   | begin_dt   | end_dt     |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| 10  |  ABC   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-21 |
| 10  |  BAC   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-21 |
| 10  |  CAS   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-21 |
| 20  |  AAA   | 2017-11-12 | 2018-01-12 |
| 20  |  DAS   | 2017-11-12 | 2018-01-12 |
| 20  |  EDS   | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-16 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

Appreciate any ideas to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1. Create new column `group_id` with `null` value if `begin_dt` is within date range from the previous row; otherwise a unique integer
2. Backfill `null`s in `group_id` with the `last` non-null value
3. Compute `min(begin_dt)` and `max(end_dt)` within each (`key, group_id)` partition

Example below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  (10, "ABC", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-08"),
  (10, "BAC", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-15"),
  (10, "CAS", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-21"),
  (20, "AAA", "2017-11-12", "2018-01-03"),
  (20, "DAS", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-12"),
  (20, "EDS", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-16")
).toDF("key", "code", "begin_dt", "end_dt")

val win1 = Window.partitionBy($"key").orderBy($"begin_dt", $"end_dt")
val win2 = Window.partitionBy($"key", $"group_id")

df.
  withColumn("group_id", when(
      $"begin_dt".between(lag($"begin_dt", 1).over(win1), lag($"end_dt", 1).over(win1)), null
    ).otherwise(monotonically_increasing_id)
  ).
  withColumn("group_id", last($"group_id", ignoreNulls=true).
      over(win1.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
  ).
  withColumn("begin_dt2", min($"begin_dt").over(win2)).
  withColumn("end_dt2", max($"end_dt").over(win2)).
  orderBy("key", "begin_dt", "end_dt").
  show
// +---+----+----------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
// |key|code|  begin_dt|    end_dt|     group_id| begin_dt2|   end_dt2|
// +---+----+----------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
// | 10| ABC|2018-01-01|2018-01-08|1047972020224|2018-01-01|2018-01-21|
// | 10| BAC|2018-01-03|2018-01-15|1047972020224|2018-01-01|2018-01-21|
// | 10| CAS|2018-01-03|2018-01-21|1047972020224|2018-01-01|2018-01-21|
// | 20| AAA|2017-11-12|2018-01-03| 455266533376|2017-11-12|2018-01-12|
// | 20| DAS|2018-01-01|2018-01-12| 455266533376|2017-11-12|2018-01-12|
// | 20| EDS|2018-02-01|2018-02-16| 455266533377|2018-02-01|2018-02-16|
// +---+----+----------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. You are the best!

Comment: I want a column like group_id. However, it should start from a specific number and increase by 1. Any suggestion please..

Comment: @Lux, unfortunately `monotonically_increasing_id` only guarantees generating unique increasing numbers.  To have more control on the generated numbers, you would have to consider using Window function without partition (which doesn't scale) or converting to RDD for its `zipWithIndex` method as shown in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094424/6316508).